# Android Studio Progress Bar Move

Tags: android

I put a progress bar in my android studio project , and  want it to move , but i don't know how to do that . I tried to look for tutorials on YouTube and follow along , but that didn't work out for me. Then i looked on google for tutorials but that didn't work for me . When i search them up i only see tutorials with the circle loading bars and I want mine to be horizontal . I only know where to start the loading bar but i really want to know how to make it move and then go into the game . I don't have any code because when i seen that it wasn't working i just deleted it . If anybody has a good tutorial or code that could help me i would appreciate very much . Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

have very easy way to use progress bar within whole code

**custom_progressbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CustomProgressBar.java**

```
public class CustomProgressBar extends Dialog {

    Activity activity;

    public CustomProgressBar(Activity act) {
        super(act);
        this.activity = act;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressbar);

        setCancelable(false);

//        set backgroung transparent
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    }

}
```

**and apply whenever you want activity or fragment**

```
   public CustomProgressBar customProgressBar;
  customProgressBar = new CustomProgressBar(context);

 customProgressBar.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressBar progressBar;
private TextView loading;

private int progressStatus = 0;

private Handler pHandler = new Handler();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    loading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus ++;
                android.os.SystemClock.sleep(50);
                pHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });

            }
            pHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loading.setText("COMPLETE");
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

}
```

This code works. You should be able to use the default XML code for the ProgressBar. You will need to add the elements, for example, the actual progress bar in the visual design. You will need to add an extra '}' at the end I think.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: Infact you have to code for the horizontal progress bar movement and set its progress, it's specially used in downloading to show percentage of operation completion.

XML code:

```
      <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:minWidth="200dp"
            android:progress="1" />
```

java code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     private ProgressBar progressBar;
     private int progressStatus = 0;
     private TextView textView;
     private Handler handler = new Handler();

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
      textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     //Long operation by thread
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
               progressStatus += 1;
      //Update progress bar with completion of operation
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
           textView.setText(progressStatus+"/"+progressBar.getMax());
        }
            });
            try {
               // Sleep for 200 milliseconds. 
                             //Just to display the progress slowly
               Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }
      }).start();
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items 
                    //to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
      return true;
     }
    }
```

Comment: In Your main activity what is text view 1 ?

Comment: and you say it's specifically for downloading something . What is it called in clash of clans or boom beach when the game is loading ??

Comment: hi @robert, here we go for your answer: 1. I have use textview to show progress bar percentage of completion (loading completion's percentage).

Comment: 2. Secondly, i wrote, to specially used for downloading/show percentage of completion or loading. And if we will talk about the clash of clans or boom beach, then it's also for showing percentage of completion of operation, which is loading of there files and other stuffs. By the way, downloading is the type of operation which includes loading itself. Therefore don't get confused.

Comment: was that help to you? let me know did you solve your problem of horizontal progress....

Comment: No i'm still having problems

Answer (score 0):

.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="50">
<ProgressBar

    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:indeterminate="false"

    android:id="@+id/Bar1"

    android:max="10"

    android:padding="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp">

    </ProgressBar>



<Button

    android:id="@+id/button1"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:onClick="startProgress"

    android:text="Start" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.dell.vlakna;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import static com.example.dell.vlakna.R.layout.activity_main;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar bar;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_main);
        bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.Bar1);

    }

    public void startProgress(View view) {

        bar.setProgress(0);
        new Thread(new Task()).start();
    }

    class Task implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                final int value = i;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                bar.setProgress(value);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

this code run good.

Comment: The progress bar isn't moving

Comment: You can look in my post and see the code that i put in .

Comment: download my project and copy your code to my running. 

I don't have time for study your code and correrct. 

in my project every 1 second progress bar go. 
Its managed with FOR cyklus